# How can I create a list where if a[0] or a[1] of a row of list a are not present in any rows of list b that row in list a is appended to list c?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists `a` eg:

```
a = [[1, 3, 7], [3, 5, 7], [-23, -34, -45]]
```

and another list `b` eg:

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to create a list `c` where when the items in the first two columns of a single row of list `a` are not present in list `b` that row of a is appended to list c. In the example lists c would look like:

```
c = [[7], [7], [-45]]
```

as the first row of `a` contains 1 and 3, both of which are present in `b` and the 2nd row contains 3 which is present in `b`.

I have tried the following without success:

```
for row in a:
    if row[0] or row[1] not in b:
        c.append(a)
```

and

```
for row in a:
    if row[1] not in b:
        if row[0] not in b:
            c.append(a)
```

as both just seem to copy `a` into `b`

Does anyone know why my code isn't working/code that would instead?

edit: apologies, I got my expected result wrong the first time round

edit 2: I messed up big time - I was designing it all wrong, my input lists are coming from another source and I had copied them down wrong. So what I am actually looking to do is as follows

```
c = [ ]

a = [[1, 3, -23], [3, 5, -34], [7, 7, -45]]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for row in a:
    if row[0] not in b and row[1] not in b:
        c.append(row)
```

Thanks for everyone who helped. sorry I'm such an idiot.

Comment: What your function should do is very unclear to me. Your definitions seem contradictory

Comment: Is it any clearer now, I'd messed up the expected result because I forgot to add the third column

Comment: Except it's still off, because you say if the first two columns are _not_ present in b, the third column should be added.  The first row shouldn't be added, then, and so it should be `c = [[7], [-45]]`.

Comment: "when the items in the first two columns of a single row of list a are not present in list b that row of a is appended to list c" So if a[0] or a[1] is in b then append a to c. Does it not read like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight modification on @muzulget's answer:

```
for row in a:
    if row[0] not in b or row[1] not in b:
        c.append(a[2])
```

Comment: This isn't quite the answer since I messed up the question but it is close

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sets` and `list comprehensions`:

```
[row[2] for row in a if set(b)-set(row[:2]) != set(b)] # prints [7, 7]
```

Comment: I need c to end up as a list of lists as multiple rows could be added to it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe wrong condition?

```
for row in a:
    if row[0] not in b or row[1] not in b:
        c.append(a)
```

`row[0]` is true if is none-zero, so why always copy a to b.

Comment: This still copies all the values in a into c for me

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the line `c.append(a)`, @mattg's answer is what your want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with:

```
c = [row[2:] for row in a if row[0] in b or row[1] in b]
```

or, with sets:

```
b_set = set(b)
c = [row[2:] for row in a if not set(row[:2]).isdisjoint(b_set)]
```

test:

```
>>> a = [[1, 3, 7], [3, 5, 7], [-23, -34, -45]]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c = [row[2:] for row in a if row[0] in b or row[1] in b]
>>> print c
[7, 7]
```

Seems to fit your last definition in the comments. Not sure it's the right one though `;)`

Comment: I need c to still be a list of lists as it may end up having multiple rows added to it

Comment: fixed, but your sample doesn't show why the list of lists would be useful

Comment: Sorry about that - I just drew up a quick example of a sample and didn't think of demonstrating that fact.